# How to delete theme submited at wordpress.org

Tags: wordpress

I have submited wrong details while uploading theme.is there any way to remove my submited theme.My theme status is not approved yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact a Team Leader and ask him to remove your theme. I think that it can only be done at the end of the review process. I advise you to use [Slack](https://wordpress.slack.com/?redir=%2Fmessages%2Fthemereview%2F).

> Comment in the most recent ticket for your theme cc’ing a team leader
>   to request your theme be removed from the repository. Alternatively,
>   please contact a team leader in the #themereview channel on Slack. You
>   can find team leaders here.

https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/faq/#how-do-i-remove-my-theme